# How do I adapt this housing block for Poseidon?

Tags: zeus-master-of-olympus, poseidon-moa

I'm trying to adapt [Aegius's common housing block](http://zeus.heavengames.com/misc/gameinfo/blocks) to the Poseidon expansion since it seems to be the most compact and dense block.  However, I noticed that he put in all the original Zeus culture buildings, which I suspect is not required.  What is the minimum science required to allow my common housing to upgrade to town homes?  Which set (university/observatory or inventor's workshop/laboratory) is more cost/space effective?  Which science building can I place at the top of the block next to the storage?  Is there a better (more compact) housing block to use for Poseidon than that one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of housing blocks to pick, you're probably better off using one of the 3 [Poseidon](http://zeus.heavengames.com/misc/gameinfo/blocks/mattizme_common_p.shtml) [house](http://zeus.heavengames.com/misc/gameinfo/blocks/pecunia_pyramid_p.shtml) [sets](http://zeus.heavengames.com/misc/gameinfo/blocks/vinvin_common_p.shtml).

That being said, there are cases where people have adopted a few of the house blocks ([Moquel's Elite Block](http://poseidon.pecunia.nerdcamp.net/blocks/moquel_elite_p.html), [SenetEr's Common](http://poseidon.pecunia.nerdcamp.net/blocks/seneter_common_p.html),[Eraserhead's 36 Townhouse](http://poseidon.pecunia.nerdcamp.net/blocks/eraserhead_common36_p.html), and [Da Caesar's Elite](http://poseidon.pecunia.nerdcamp.net/blocks/da_caesar_elite_modified_p.html)).

Unfortunately, no one has posted a modified version of Aegius' common block. If you have already tried to re-create the block, my best recommendation is to try to recreate it yourself.

Now how do we do that? Let's look at this chart (taken from [here](http://poseidon.pecunia.nerdcamp.net/entertainment.html))

[image: chart]

You need 45 of these points to upgrade the house to a townhouse. You could probably sub out the lab for the gym, the bibliotheke for the podium, the inventor's workshop for the college, and the museum for the theater. That should be enough to get them to townhouses...